# Fastest way to deal with birthdays in mysql

Tags: mysql

Unfortunately in the project where I have to work with user's birth date stored in three different fields: day, month and year. It has type a `tinytext` field.

I'm looking for the fastest way to find users who are not older than 55 years old.

First I think that it would be nice to convert it to `INT` tiny or smallint.
Second I'm thinking about how to improve speed of query execution...
I see there are two ways:

1. Concat three fields inside query and use date related mysql functions
2. Count, on application side, wished year, month and day and compare it with one by one field. And maybe combined index for three fields will increase speed as well

Any other solution?

Comment: can you alter the DB structure?

Comment: Show us some ways and we'll tell you which one is fastest.

Comment: @serakfalcon Yeah I can but partially, cause i don't want make changes everywhere in application. I have to deal with that because it's used in search engine and it makes it slow

Comment: You could add a column with the data type date and handle its value with triggers to build upon @serakfalcon.

Comment: @VMai yeah, I thought about that. But this I would left for last thing what I'm going to do.

Comment: What's your table size (and how much is it going to grow)? If the table is not to be modified, I'd fetch all the users that are not older than 56 years and eliminate the day/month difference cases in the application.